# OneToMany relationship using non-primary composite key

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a table structure like this

Good Assignments Entity

```
@Embeddable
public class GoodAssignmentId {
  String clientId,
  String assignmentNumber;
  LocalDate effectiveDate;

  // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@IdClass(GoodAssignmentId.class)
class GoodAssignment {
  @id
  String clientId;

  @Id
  String assignmentNumber;
  
  @Id
  LocalDate effectiveDate;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentKey")
  Set<GoodTasks> children;
  
  String description;

  // getters and setters goes below      
}
```

Bad Assignments Entity

```
@Entity
@IdClass(BadAssignmentId.class)
class BadAssignment {
  @id
  String clientId;

  @Id
  String assignementNumber;
  
  @Id
  LocalDate effectiveDate;

  String description;

  // Getters and setters goes below
}
```

Child entities

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ParentTasksId.class)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "fieldD", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
class ParentTasks {
  @Id
  String clientId;

  @Id
  String assignmentNumber;

  @Id
  String taskNumber;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("G")
class GoodTasks extends ParentTasks {
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({
     @JoinColumn(name = "clientId", referencedColumName = "clientId"),
     @JoinColumn(name = "assignmentNumber", referencedColumName = "assignmentNumber")
   })
   GoodAssignments parentKey;
   
   other fields....
}
```

This shows the error `referencedColumnNames(fieldA, fieldB) of .... not mapped to a single property.`

Unfortunately I cannot change the table structure. `TableA` has 3 columns as primary key, but only two of them forms the primary key in table B along with another field (`fieldD` via `@DiscriminatorValue` used by multiple classes). How can I map this relationship to get list of `TableB` items in `TableA`?

Example Class Diagram:
Effective date in the assignments tables is not part of tasks. So this is not a perfect relationship in JPA terms. It's a legacy design which cannot be changed for some reasons.

[image]

Comment: Why negative votes? Please comment to understand what more information I need to provide.

Comment: It would be nice to see db tables diagram

Comment: @SternK This is a legacy system with no relationships defined. There are two tables TableA and TableB. TableA uniqueness defined by 3 columns. Out of the 3, only 2 columns are referenced in the TableB. For example, Assignment as TableA and list of Tasks as TableB. Assignments can be defined with multiple dates, so the primary key is  assignment id and effective date in TableA. But the Task is specific to the assignment irrespective of the date. So it has reference to only assignment id and not the date. If I plot this on ER diagram, there will be no primary foreign key. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Forget Jpa/hibernate for a moment, you have two records in `MainTable` with `(A1, B1, C1)` and `(A1, B1, C2)`. You have one record in `TableB` with `(A1, B1, D1)`. Now in relational world, can you tell me which record in `MainTable` you want your `(A1, B1, D1)` point to as it has two records?

Comment: I added sample diagram to show what it is. The assignments are effective dated but the tasks are not. I am trying to map relationship from Good assignments to the tasks as shown in diagram. I know there is no relationship can be formed between those tables as all columns of primary key in tableA are not defined in foriegn key in tableB. But that's how the legacy design is. Unfortunately I cannot change DB design now.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I just want to fetch the records in tableB into tableA property with matching A1, B1 columns. For each record in tableA.

Comment: @NagarjunIt It does not answer my question. There are two matching records in `MainTable`. Which one you want? Anyway I put the sample to show if you can't solve the issue logically in relational world, you can't solve it in JPA. What are the possible values for `assignment_type`?

Comment: For the record A1,B1,C1 in `MainTable`, I need to fetch all records in `TableB` with values A1,B1 and 'G' (G for tasks of good assignments). So if only one record in `TableB` with values A1,B1,D1, 'G', only one record will be fetched. assignment_type can be 'G' for good assignments, 'B' for bad assignments. While fetching the Good Assignments, I fetch them by A1,B1,effective date, it should fetch tasks matching A1, B1, 'G'

Comment: Based on the very last comment, actually you have a way of mapping because BadAssignments know their type is `B`. which is fixed. So they can reference the parent by all 3 keys.

Comment: Can you post an example code, please?

Comment: Can you actually update your question with entity `GoodAssignment`, `BadAssignment` and `Task` and I provide you an anser

Comment: Updated my code

Comment: I added code required for almost everything now.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what you described in your comment.  `GoodTasks` cannot select a `BadAssignment` without knowing `effectiveDate`, i.e there can be many `BadAssignment`  for the chosen `clientId` and `assignementNumber`.

Comment: I need not select badassignments from tasks.. i need only one direction fetch from good/bad assignments to fetch the tasks. I need not know what assignments belongs to a task, but need to know what all tasks available for an assignment.